# What is a "locus" when referring to house plumbing pipes?

Tags: wood, construction

What is a "locus"? The term was used to describe how a wooden house is set up. They used "locus pipes".

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's a "wooden house"? _Locus_ is simply the Latin root of words like _location_. It means a specific place. We'd probably need more context to help.

Comment: Could it be they were talking about "locust posts"? These are wooden columns made from locust tree trunks, often used in older homes as supports for floor joists.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that comes to mind (and it's not related to wooden house construction at all) when thinking of pipes and the word locus is that in German, "Lokus" is a term used for a toilet (perhaps it's a little nicer to say than toilet). That would fit your description of "locus pipes" - the waste pipes (and maybe supply) for the toilets.

*Source: I'm a native German speaker. Also see the German Wikipedia entry for "[Toilette](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilette)"*